# How do you use TRIM in a CAST

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a statement that is returning an error in my query in TOAD. I'm trying to Trim a Cast with this

```
CAST (TRIM ( 'N' AS VARCHAR2 (1) ) )  AS FLAG
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You want to cast the letter "N"... to what?

Comment: and the error is...??

Comment: TRIM goes before CAST, not in it.

Comment: `TRIM('N' AS VARCHAR2 (1))` doesn't make sense. What are you trying to do anyway? N is a single letter. Why the trimming, why the casting?

Comment: I posed these same concerns.  and I did have it working without error as the Trim before the cast. But my instructor says that the trim goes on the inside and I need to cast it.

Comment: Move a `)` close bracket before the `AS`. Like this: `CAST (TRIM ( 'N' ) AS VARCHAR2 (1) ) AS FLAG`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably

```
SQL> select cast (trim('N') as varchar2(1)) as flag from dual;

F
-
N

SQL>
```

Or did you actually what to TRIM a CAST?

```
SQL> select trim(cast ('N' as varchar2(1))) as flag from dual;

F
-
N

SQL>
```

---

Although, what's the point? `'N'` already is a one-letter string so casting it as `varchar2(1)` won't do anything, nor will trimming such a letter.